Adding custom tags to an AVI format file
I have a video (that was recorded in a specific software) and I saw it has tags that are not the regular AVI tags.
I'm looking for a way to change another video to have similar attributes (I changed resolution, bit rate, codec, etc..)
I can't find a way to add that tags. Is there any idea how to solve it? (I am using a macOS, if it matters).
I tried using libraries FFmpeg, Pyav, and AVI Metaedit, but the tags were not added (but it did work for the common tags such as "title")

(1) Use a hex editor to check the bytes of the AVI with those custom tags, then write or copy same bytes to your AVI file (also update the "size" bytes in the section called INFO since there will now be some new extra bytes and the player needs to know where metadata ends and the first frame begins). (2) "I can't find a way to add that tags" means you need to read the AVI specifications. A quick summary is here because AVI or WAV are classed as RIFF-type files. Read about LIST and INFO. Your AVI has a LIST/INFO section, practice updating it.

PS: Practice means try simple changes like if your "title" is hello then change it in hex editor to become hellothere. Now you have 5 new extra bytes (1 per letter) but the rest of file and player won't know you did this change, so now you change size values of both INFO and of LIST to become a new amount eg: size = (size + 5). Use any online  "integer to hex" converter to see how your size amount looks as hex bytes and type it in. When you can do it manually by hand, then write code to achieve same result.

It worked! Thank you!
